# Ordenar un array por un campo fecha PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array llamado $trazabilidad que he ido rellenando al realizar consultas SQL con los siguientes campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uno de los campos es una fecha y me gustaria ordenar el array por dicho campo, para ello uso la funcion:

```
usort($trazabilidad, strtotime(trim($trazabilidad['FECHA EXPEDIDO'])));
```

En cambio al visualizar de nuevo la tabla me aparece en el siguiente orden:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo ordenar el array para que aparezca por orden real de fecha?

Comment: Por que no lo ordenas por fecha directamente en la consulta SQL ?

Answer (score 2):

Estas usando mal la función [usort](http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php), le tienes que pasar como parámetro la función que se debe ejecutar por cada elemento, no un valor concreto.

Sería algo así:

```
<?php

 function compara_fecha($a, $b){
    return strtotime(trim($a['fecha'])) > strtotime(trim($b['fecha']));
 }

 $trazabilidad = array (
   array('lote'=>1010, 'fecha'=>'01/03/2019'),        
   array('lote'=>1100, 'fecha'=>'01/01/2019'),
   array('lote'=>1011, 'fecha'=>'01/06/2019'),   
 );

 // usort($trazabilidad, strtotime(trim($trazabilidad['fecha'])));
 usort($trazabilidad, 'compara_fecha');
 var_dump($trazabilidad);
```